# Grails, getting InputStream from Controller (or even Servlet)

Tags: grails, controller, inputstream

I'm trying to get inputStream from request, but it's always empty. Any idea
how to get the contents of it? I'm trying to make a DataInputStream from it.

Comment: How you send your data? You should know if the data come as `MultipartFile` or `ByteArray`. If you send a file, you should retrieve it like: `request.getFile('file')`. But if it's a `ByteArray`, `InputStream` should be filled with it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you uploading multipart requests? The request may have already been processed into a Spring MultipartRequest by Grails in which case you can use getFile() to get the upload contents.

If not, then request.inputStream should work fine.

cheers

Lee

Comment: No, I'm not doing multipart. The weird thing is, I created a servlet and register it in web.xml (grails install-templates), but its request.getInputStream() is empty too. Being curious, I extracted that very same servlet into a new ordinary Java Web (Eclipse New Project), and it works. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea, that sounds very strange. Can you reproduce it with a brand new Grails app? If so, I'd create a JIRA bug report and attach the example project.

Answer (score 2):

For me it works when I request the controller method with "application/octet-stream" MIME and send some data within the request. Than in the controller I can simply do:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def test() {
   byte[] requestData = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream())
}
```

That's it :-)

Comment: From where should import `IOUtils `?

Comment: It's apache library `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`, will fix my answer...

Comment: Thanks, finally I used `grails.io`because `org.apache.commons.io` import couldn't be solved in my project.